# Excel: How to exclude Errors from Filter function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using the array formula below in Excel I get 5 results and 5 empty rows as intended

```
FILTER(MyDatatable; MyDatatable[column2] = A1; "Nothing found")
```

However the 5 empty rows return #N/A and I can't get rid of them using IFNA or IFERROR

any suggestions?

Comment: I think cell `A1` shows the value of a Sheetname and you want to reference to it dynamically. You can only do this by using INDIRECT. For instance: `INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!I912)

Comment: In this way it works, but I'm not sure if it is best practice: =FILTER(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISERROR(A:A)));FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISERROR(A:A)))=B2)

Answer (score 1):

`=FILTER(MyDatatable; MyDatatable[column2]=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!I92");"Nothing found")` is most likely what you want. As explained in my comment.

Comment: The !I92 in my initial question was a copy-paste error on my part in an effort to simplify the problem. My bad! The first cell of the sheet A1 just contains the the criterium to be used with the filter. So the problem remains. Thnx anyway for your input

Comment: Than I don't see the problem. Maybe wrong reference? The logic is alright: [logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZNy.jpg)